# Why does the Struct *node next works for linked list in C++?

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list

Wouldn't it be the same to just have an embedded object of the same structure that is not a pointer?

```
Struct Node
{
int data;
Node next;
};
//vs
Struct Node
{
int data;
Node * next;
};
```

Comment: Do you come to C++ from Python or Java?

Comment: If you have a house, can you embed another similar house inside that house ? No. But you can leave a note in that house with the address of another house.

Comment: @nos: nice example I like it

Answer (score 1):

**No!**

Having the following struct:

```
struct Node {
    Node other;
};
```

Is illegal! `Node` doesn't have a defined size; the compiler can't build it correctly. A `Node` would contain a `Node` which would contain a `Node`.. wait what?

A pointer however is fine, it just points to a section of memory. When defining a pointer, the type that it points to doesn't have to be complete, it just has to *defined*.

```
struct Node;

int main() {
    Node* a; // Fine, no errors.
    Node b; // Incomplete type error
}
```